# Writing a file returns empty file

Tags: java

I've started to learn Java and working with files is a little bit hard for me. Can you check my code and see what's going wrong?

```
public class Arena  {
FileWriter f = createFile();
protected void print(String me){
        try {
            f.write(me);
            System.out.println(me);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    protected FileWriter createFile() {
        try {
            return new FileWriter("src/battle.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And this method print I use as System.out.println
But when I run my code my file battle.txt is empty. How I can fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

You need to `close()` your `FileWriter`. Currently, you open it at the class level and never close it. I would use a `try-with-Resources` and something like

```
protected void print(String me) {
    try (FileWriter f = createFile()) {
        f.write(me);
        System.out.println(me);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which should resolve your issue.